# Error Installing Ice 3.6 for Python on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ice

I tried to install Ice 3.6 for python by pip:

```
pip install zeroc-ice
```

and got these errors:

```
Collecting zeroc-ice
  Using cached zeroc-ice-3.6.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: zeroc-ice
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zeroc-ice ... error
  Complete output from command /home/phan/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-D__B7T/zeroc-ice/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpKbigqspip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only .-separated package names in setup.py
...
...
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    src/ice/cpp/src/IceUtil/SHA1.cpp:19:31: fatal error: openssl/sha.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I used anaconda2 for python 2.7.

Comment: after trying various solution to install ice on ubuntu, pip worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I install openssl

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```